# Are the abbreviations IMO and IMHO synonymous to each other?

Tags: abbreviations, figures-of-speech

Is there a difference between IMO (In My Opinion) and IMHO (In My Honest Opinion)? You see both forms frequently being used in online conversatiosn. Do they mean the same, or is there a slight difference in meaning?

Comment: I thought it was "In My Humble Opinion"

Comment: I personally use them interchangeably, I seriously doubt that stating that your opinion is "humble" in abbreviation makes the recipient view your statement in some other way. But I guess it is only my humble opinion, as self-deprecation (as stated by Barrie) might mean something for someone.

Answer (score 4):

The *H* stands for 'humble', not 'honest'. So *IMHO* is self-deprecatory. *IMO* is not.

Comment: Interesting.  I've generally assumed it meant honest, as well.  Probably because I've more commonly heard the phrase with honest than with humble.  Do AE speakers value honesty above humility or do I just surround myself with a less humble crowd?  Phrases like "honestly, I think..." and "to be honest..." are intriguing ways to preface opinions, I think.

Comment: I'm new to Ngrams, but it appears that humble opinions are 100-fold more popular than honest opinions!

Answer (score 0):

In my *humble* opinion, not honest. Thus no, they are not equivalents, since IMO is not humble.